# Default file startup location

Tags: blend-files

I do not know what I did wrong but for some reason, my default file startup location is somewhere else in my system and its awkward that it is ALREADY saved (it asks me "Save Over? ")

How can I reset this to a default unsaved file and in a location that 'I' alone have specified?[image]

Comment: Are you really sure that is default file location? That is neither Blender default folder location (its name as well) nor its structure is the same. Default Blender startup file is in Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\version (as it's likely you use Windows). The path on the screenshot seems to be something not related to official Blender at all. Where did you install it from? How it was done?

Comment: @MrZak  I installed it from blender.org. 64 bit Microsoft installer. I've been using it for months now and its just recently that this nonsense started. It no longer shows me a save screen when I hit Ctrl+S, rather it shows me a popup asking if I want to overwrite that file as named title in the title bar (user_not_saved.blend).

Comment: How is the file called which you are edting? Did you save the file under this name? (user_not_saved). This is not Blender startup file nor Blender shows save screen when pressing Ctrl+S, rather it asks you if it's ok to overwrite the file being edited at the moment.

Comment: I know its not Blender Startup mode at all and that's what it gives to me on EVERY startup (user_not_saved...so I never saved it under this name at all. And when I traced the location, I found these (image below) like its creating "user_not_saved" on every startup for me without allowing me to hit Ctrl+S and choose a location and filename that I desire. Ive even uninstalled and reinstalled yet still the same. Ive deleted the entire "cr" folder but it still came back. Blender is creating this nonsense....weird. @MrZak

Comment: This is not how Blender is supposed to work at all. So I think probably you should check your system on some problems besides Blender. Regarding Blender, check what addons you installed, ones which tend to change interface and startup defaults in particular. Generally try disabling all the addons, saving that in configuration(Ctrl+U) and trying again. Backup copy of the configuration if you want to have that as saved. You can also load factory settings and save that with Ctrl+U as well.

Comment: I opened Blender and loaded factory settings, saved startup file, reopened Blender but it didn't work. So I Reloaded factory settings again, saved startup file AND saved user settings from the Preferences window and it WORKED! Thank you! Looks like the issue was from the startup file which ALSO had something to do with the user preferences.....which seems weird to me though. Thanks again @MrZak